# Autocomplete of composite component attributes in STS

Tags: eclipse, jsf, composite-component, code-completion, spring-tool-suite

I have created some composite components in my JSF project in STS 3.1.0. When I declare them in the view like this:

```
xmlns:asw="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/asw-tags
```

then everything works fine, but I don't have any code completion for attributes which are definied on the composite component. How can I enable code completion in STS?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557201/how-to-make-eclipse-autocomplete-work-with-jsf-composite-components-in-jar

Comment: Excuse me, I haven't mention that I use STS 3.1.0. which works with eclipse 3.7.

Comment: That aren't exactly "custom components", I fixed the improper terminology. Further I wonder why you're using a Spring-targeted IDE instead of a Java EE targeted IDE. It works out the box in Eclipse for Java EE and even better so when using JBoss Tools plugin.

Comment: At certain point we've started migrating a large application to Spring, and then we made one small part of that application autonomous and we've strted to migrate to jsf instead of old jsp pages. During that first period with Spring we decided to try STS and we were satisfied, but now we see some problems. Maybe we will decide to return to Eclipse for Java EE but we hoped that Eclipse 3.8.1 which is included in STS would answer our needs